# Unable to install SproutCore

Tags: sproutcore

I used

```
rvm 1.8.7 do gem install sproutcore
```

It was installed successfully, but now on running `sproutcore gen project getting_started` 
it gives me the following errors:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/sproutcore-1.8.2.1/vendor/chance/lib/chance/instance/slicing.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
            mtime: file[:mtime],
                  ^
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/sproutcore-1.8.2.1/vendor/chance/lib/chance/instance/slicing.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
            canvas: canvas
                   ^
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/sproutcore-1.8.2.1/vendor/chance/lib/chance/instance/slicing.rb:234: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a "known bug" with Ruby 1.8.7 as it's using some syntax that is only available in 1.9.

You should probably try upgrading to Ruby 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 which should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Topher Fangio, but to add how: this is what I did.

```
gem update --system
```